# How to use multiline EOF in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to isntall an R package from the command line using docker.  I don't get how to use EOF with docker

Below is my dockerfile:

```
Step 8/8 : RUN R --vanilla <<EOF install.packages('plyr', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org') q() EOF
 ---> Running in 767d4e577542
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
The command '/bin/sh -c R --vanilla <<EOF install.packages('plyr', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org') q() EOF' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  instead wrap your R command in a script (in which you can have multiple lines and EOF)

You would [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) your script first (from your local context to your image), then [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) it in your Dockerfile.